# Is "flip your glove inside out" idiomatic?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Is "flip your glove inside out" idiomatic? I know that the expression is "turn your glove inside out", but sometimes I see "flip" being used, but it doesn't seem to be standard, idiomatic or even correct, because Google gives very few results, especially for "flip your glove inside out".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with "flip" is that it implies a quick motion, and it's not obvious see how to *quickly* turn a glove inside-out.

It might make more sense if you explained the action (or sequence of actions) necessary to do this:

> If you want to **flip a glove inside-out** to let it dry off, what you do is this:  Put your hand in the glove and lightly curl your fingers.  Grasp the bottom edge of the glove and peel it up so it turns inside-out as you remove it.  If you do this quickly but smoothly, the glove should be inside-out, all the way to the fingertips, by the time you are done.

Answer (score 0):

The expression is "turn your glove inside out" is idiomatic. Its not very common, because not many people turn gloves inside out, or if they do then they don't need to be told it. "Flip..." is fine, it suggests a quicker motion.

But why?  "I know that the expression is "turn your glove inside out" [is idiomatic], sometimes I see "flip" being used"  This tells you all you need to know.   I'm amazed that you have ever heard enough English spoken to hear such an expression twice. I'm sure that I never have.